# View not removed from its superview in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` and a `collectionView`. If there is an internet connection I want to hide the `collectionView` and show the `UIView`, if not otherwise.

```
class MyClass{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var myView : CustomView?
    ....

    func internetStatusChanegd(){
        if(isOnline){
            collectionView.isHidden = true
            if let viewNib = UIView.loadFromNibNamed("CustomView", bundle: Bundle.main) as? CustomView {
                myView = viewNib
                myView!.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.view.addSubview(myView!)
            }
        }else{
            if let customView = myView{
                customView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            collectionView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

`removeFromSuperview()` Is called but the view is not removed from the view. Do you have an idea about the problem?

Comment: Probably `myView` is `nil`

Comment: No, I debugged the code and its not nil. But the problem is that even setting isHidden to true dont make it disappear

Comment: Then you have probably added the same view more than once, but you have only one of those instances being referenced by your property.

Comment: good tip, I think internetStatusChanegd() is being called twice

Answer (score 0):

**Remove like this**

```
for subview in self.view.subviews{
   if subview is CustomView
   {
      subview.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. While adding a sub view in my view give a tag to that view.
2. Iterate the for loop for subviews in view.
3. While removing just check if it's the view with same tag then call-

   self.removeFromSuperview()

Answer (score 0):

Please remove already available view before you are adding new view.

```
func internetStatusChanegd() {
    if(isOnline) {
        collectionView.isHidden = true
        for subView in (self.view.subviews)! {
            if (subView.tag == 100) {
                subView.removeFromSuperview() //this will remove already available object form self.view
            }
        }
        if let viewNib = UIView.loadFromNibNamed("CustomView", bundle: Bundle.main) as? CustomView {
            myView = viewNib
            myView!.frame = self.view.bounds
            myView.tag = 100 //add tag when you create object
            self.view.addSubview(myView!)
        }
    }else{
        if let customView = myView{
            customView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        collectionView.isHidden = false}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isOnline{
        collectionView.backgroundView = myView //your custom view whatever you want to show here like : button..
        return 0
    }
    collectionView.backgroundView = nil
    return array.count
}
func internetStatusChanegd(){ collectionView.reloadData() } //it'll handle automatically that view .
```

**Try this**